# Android fragments and image from internal storage has delay

Tags: android, bitmap, android-fragments

i'm working with fragments and some of the fragments can contain images.

I first download the image to internal storage then when the oncreateview is called i want to show the image on the fragment.

I do this with the following code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getActivity().getFileStreamPath(image).getAbsolutePath());

    ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ivStory))
            .setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

the problem is that when i swipe to the fragment it has an delay 'about 2 seconds'..

I've been messing around with an LRUcache today but it seems to not work..

Does someone has a clue? Is the image to big? Because it should run on an tablet too so it has to be an big resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems is that the `decodeFile` method takes time to execute. You should execute the `decodeFile` method on separate thread (not on the `UI-Thread`) and once it is done use  a `Handler` to update the `UI`.